# Random SYN_SENT connections to Amazon EC2?

Tags: tcp, ubuntu, amazon

I have looked around but couldn't find anyone else with this issue. On my console (standard asus i7 laptop) running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - I noticed in tcptrack that there are a lot of connections being made to an ip address belonging to Amazon EC2 services. I don't have any connection to amazon at all, and these connections are all status SYN_SENT. IP examples: 50.17.195.149 and 54.243.128.120.

Is this a security offense of any kind, or is there a rational explanation?

Thanks in advance.

Check out the output from tcptrack immediately after opening chrome. 
[image]

Netstat Output:
[image]

Comment: Use the `netstat`command that (given the correct arguments; check its manual page) will tell you which process is responsible for making the connection.

Comment: The target server in your screenshot looks like a shared web server for Dynahost; see for yourself : http://50.17.195.149 - in any case this seems suspicious and you should definitely identify which process does this.

Comment: Netstat shows in this case that the process origin is Chrome itself.. (screen shot att.) I have no extensions active at all. (Apart from Google Docs)
Now I am thinking this is an adware bug??

Comment: What if you open Chrome but don't open any tabs ? Do the connections still appear ? If yes, it's an extension, if not it's just a website linking to a resource on that server, nothing to be afraid of.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that in the question, sorry, it happens regardless of tabs, as soon as you open chrome. I have no extensions apart from Google Docs, which would unlikely be the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed this same phenomenon with my Ubuntu 14.04 machine today (all kinds of connections to EC2 instances such as `ec2-52-22-249-100.compute-1.amazonaws.com` from Chrome), and on my machine at least, Ghostery and the DuckDuckGo search engine integrated with the omnibar both seemed to call out to EC2. You mention you don't have any extensions installed, what about other search engines?

By disabling Ghostery and closing Chrome completely, waiting a few minutes for the TCP connections all to close, then starting up Chrome, the connections eventually stopped. The instant I checked the box to enable Ghostery, they started back up. For DDG, I noticed it made EC2 connections after performing a search through the omnibar.

Comment: While it's clear that you meant to provide an answer, it ended up being more a comment than an answer. Such chatty answers are discouraged on stackexchange sites. I hope you won't take it personally if this answer gets downvoted or even deleted

Comment: I've edited the post to hopefully make it less chatty? I don't know what would be a definitive answer here because it could be due to several things on the asker's machine, but I'm trying to contribute some useful data points to rule out, and I don't have enough reputation to comment. Let me know if there's a better way for me to go about this.

Comment: Much better. Nice job

Comment: Somehow I never got notified about this answer being given. I have lost the context by now, but I am pretty sure this is the right answer. :-)